# Power Regression Unit Conversion

Tags: nonlinear-regression, gradient-descent

Say I have fit parameters $a, b, c$ for a power regression model (using SGD and a MSE loss),

$$y = ax^b + c.$$

Suppose the derived $a, b, c$ fit the data very well. Now suppose $x$ undergoes a change in units, so that $\tilde{x} \equiv x + \alpha$, and now I want to fit a model

$$y = a'\tilde{x} ^ {b'} + c'.$$

Is there a way to leverage the previous $a, b, c$ for fitting the new $a', b', c'$? Perhaps either by some formula converting $a \rightarrow a', b \rightarrow b', c \rightarrow c'$, or some way to initialize $a', b', c'$ to facilitate learning?

I find that I get stuck in suboptimal minima when using SGD with $\{\tilde{x}, y\}$, and cannot fit as good a model as with $\{x, y\}$.

I think this is an interesting problem, because in theory units should not affect the ultimate goodness of fit our model achieves.

Comment: Unfortunately, the units *do* affect this model unless $b=1$ or $b=0$ or $a=0.$  You can see this through algebraic manipulation of special simple cases.  For instance, with $b=2$ the model for the shifted variable is $y = a(x+\alpha)^2+c=ax^2 + (2a\alpha)x + (a\alpha^2+c).$ A nonzero coefficient of $x$ appears where there wasn't one before, *QED.*  In some cases, especially where the variation in $x$ is small compared to its average value, you can use a Taylor series approximation to get a good start value for the new model.

Comment: @gfppoy scaling ($x' = \alpha x$) would work just fine, but translation doesn't

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the useful takeaway is that units actually can affect goodness of fit, depending on the family of models and the units.